# Why annotation based libraries are not so popular in Scala?

Tags: scala, annotations

When I write Java code, I found annotation based libraries are very popular, e.g. `hibernate`, `Jackson`, `Gson`, `Spring-MVC`. But in Scala, most of the popular libraries are not providing annotations, or provided but recommend non-annotation approaches, e.g. `squerly`, `slick`, `argonaut`, `unfiltered`, etc.

Sometimes, I found the annotations are easier to read and maintain, but why people are not so interested in them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason is that annotations often have to be used at declaration-site. Hence, you have to "pollute" your domain models with code not relevant to your business logic. Solutions based on macros or type classes on the other hand are usually applied on use-site. This allows higher reusability of your domain models.

E.g., what if you need different serialization logic for different tasks? With annotations you have usually no other choice than implementing an additional representation of your model with modified annotations. With type classes (probably automatically derived through macros), you have to just implement another instance and inject it accordingly to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Macros and implicits can often be used as a substitute for annotations and have the benefit of being statically checked.